# What happens to Voldemort's physical body when he possesses Harry?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

When Voldemort possesses Harry Potter during the battle at the Ministry of Magic at the end of *Order of the Phoenix*, his physical body seems to disappear from the scene:

> For a few seconds Voldemort was visible only as a dark, rippling, faceless figure, shimmering and indistinct upon the plinth, clearly struggling to throw off the suffocating mass.
>
> Then **he was gone** and the water fell with a crash back into its pool, slopping wildly over the sides, drenching the polished floor.
>
> 'MASTER!' screamed Bellatrix.
>
> Sure it was over, sure Voldemort had decided to flee, Harry made to run out from behind his statue guard, but Dumbledore bellowed: 'Stay where you are, Harry!'
>
> For the first time, Dumbledore sounded frightened. Harry could not see why: the hall was quite empty but for themselves, the sobbing Bellatrix still trapped under the witch statue, and the baby phoenix Fawkes croaking feebly on the floor.
>
> Then Harry's scar burst open and he knew he was dead: it was pain beyond imagining, pain past endurance.

**Where does Voldemort's body go while he's possessing Harry?**

Does it disappear entirely? Does he Disapparate it somewhere else, before returning to pick up Bellatrix and flee? Is it somehow 'inside' Harry's body?

Comment: relevant question that should probably be linked (I see that you've read it already): [Was Voldemort properly present during the MoM encounter after trying to possess Harry?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106187/was-voldemort-properly-present-during-the-mom-encounter-after-trying-to-possess)

Comment: @sumelic Yeah, that question and DVK's answer were what inspired this one.

Answer (score 3):

I think Voldemort Disapparate his body to somewhere else, before returning to pick up Bellatrix and flee

Based on Snape's comments, Harry has to be in relaxed (or Voldemort being agitated) to be able to enter into Voldemort's head.

> The evidence suggests that at times, when your mind is most relaxed and vulnerable - when you are asleep, for instance - you are sharing the Dark Lord’s thoughts and emotions.
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 24, Occlumency*</sup></sub>

**The vice-versa of this could also be true.** If it is true, then it looks likely that  Voldemort disapparated to some place safe and used his connection with Harry Potter to possess him.  We know the connection between Harry and Voldemort is very strong and geography has no impact on it.

> “The Dark Lord is at a considerable distance and the walls and grounds of Hogwarts are guarded by many ancient spells and charms to ensure the bodily and mental safety of those who dwell within them,” said Snape. “Time and space matter in magic, Potter. Eye contact is often essential to Legilimency.”
>
> “Well then, why do I have to learn Occlumency?”
>
> Snape eyed Harry, tracing his mouth with one long, thin finger as he did so.
>
> “The usual rules do not seem to apply with you, Potter. The curse that failed to kill you seems to have forged some kind of connection between you and the Dark Lord. The evidence suggests that at times, when your mind is most relaxed and vulnerable - when you are asleep, for instance - you are sharing the Dark Lord’s thoughts and emotions. The Headmaster thinks it inadvisable for this to continue. He wishes me to teach you how to close your mind to the Dark Lord.”
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix, Chapter 24, Occlumency*</sup></sub>

I am saying this because Voldemort cannot be in relaxed state if has to deal with Dumbledore.

Comment: Snape never says Harry *has* to be relaxed for the possession to work, just that that's when it often happens.

Comment: I agree with you, but I wanted to emphasize the point that Voldemort would have found it hard (or impossible) to possess Harry if Voldemort was in the same room as Harry and Dumbledore.

Answer (score 3):

**He could very well be inside Harry** or **Nothing - at least not as a direct result of the possession**

The answer really depends on how you interpret the quotes and for that reason I am going to give a discussion for both sides.

The first example I'm going to look at is the **Pensieve!**

> Harry was thrown forward and **pitched headfirst into the substance** inside the basin – 
> But his head did not hit the stone bottom. He was falling through something icycold and black; it was like being sucked into a dark whirlpool – 
>  
> *Goblet of Fire - Scholastic Ebook - Page 373*

Another excerpt from OOTP:

> He took a great gulp of breath, and plunged his face into the surface of Snape’s thoughts. 
> At
> once, the floor of the office lurched, **tipping Harry head-first into the Pensieve…**
> He was falling through cold blackness, spinning furiously as he went, and then - 
> *Order of the Phoenix - Scholastic Ebook - Page 482*

There is also an answer [here](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/96427/22709) on the same topic.

In this answer @Richard also talks about the language used to describe his return from the Pensieve and the fact that Snape has to go into the memory to retrieve Harry from it instead of just raising his head out of the Pensieve.

However one can also ask the question "If his body is in there how would Snape know he was in there?" we can also argue that the language used is merely a feeling that is Happening to Harry rather than the actual action. (Like the feeling of falling when going to sleep)

**Pensieve Notes**

When Harry talks to **Toms diary** in CoS the diary says "I can show you" the following quote then seems to describe Harry being absorbed into the book similarly to the Pensieve.

> Harry saw that the little square for June thirteenth seemed to have turned into a miniscule television screen. His hands trembling slightly, he raised the book to press his eye against the little window, and before he knew what was happening, he was tilting forward; the window was widening, **he felt his body leave his bed**, and he was pitched headfirst through the opening in the page, into a whirl of color and shadow. 
>  
> *Chamber of Secrets - Scholastic Ebook - Page 158*

Following this we have a description of Harry coming out of the diary:

> Harry felt himself falling and, **with a crash, he landed spread-eagled** on his four-poster in the Gryffindor dormitory, Riddle’s diary lying open on his stomach. 
> Before he had had time to regain his breath, the dormitory door opened and Ron came in.
> **“There you are,”** he said

The language used definitely implies he fell from somewhere or was ejected from somewhere with some sort of force at least. We also have the comment from Ron which seems to imply that Ron was looking for him, it seems obvious that he would have checked the dorm room before and Harry was clearly not present.

Other than the language points mentioned before there's not really much of an argument against this point apart from it's possible Ron had just gotten into the Dorm when Harry stops peering into the book.

There is only one description of **Legilimency** that we have available:

> A hundred Dementors were swooping towards Harry across the lake in the grounds… he
> screwed up his face in concentration… they were coming closer… he could see the dark holes
> beneath their hoods… yet he could also see Snape standing in front of him, his eyes fixed on
> Harry’s face, muttering under his breath… and somehow, Snape was growing clearer, and the
> Dementors were growing fainter…
> Harry raised his own wand.
> “Protego!”
> Snape staggered - his wand flew upwards, away from Harry - and suddenly Harry’s mind was
> teeming with memories that were not his: a hook-nosed man was shouting at a cowering woman,
> while a small dark-haired boy cried in a corner… a greasy-haired teenager sat alone in a dark
> bedroom, pointing his wand at the ceiling, shooting down flies… a girl was laughing as a
> scrawny boy tried to mount a bucking broomstick -
> “ENOUGH!”
> *Order of the Phoenix - Scholastic Ebook - Page 446*

The above does not feature any of the language present in the former quotes to suggest an absorption of ones body into the memory. This is also probably the most related piece of magic to what is being used between Voldemort and Harry, although it could be argued because of the Scar being <s>not a</s> Horcrux the magic is most related to the Diary.

For the reasons listed above I believe that it is largely based on your Interpretation of the language being used as to where you think Voldemort goes.

**Discussing the actual scene**

We all know that after Voldemort is finished with Harry he reappears and then takes Bellatrix and leaves. In the scene he is actually forcibly ejected by Harrys or by his strong feelings of love which cause Voldemort pain.

To me it makes little sense for Voldemort to return from wherever he was to simple collect Bellatrix and then leave again. It would make more sense if he was ejected from Harry and then returned to the room from his mind, forced to retreat he collects his Lieutenant and leaves. *Some may argue that he cares for Bellatrix and returned for that reason which is entirely plausible*

It is also plausible that he returned not to run away again but to finish off Dumbledore and Harry, until the MoM shows up and ruins his plans he then makes the tactical decision to retreat.

> For a few seconds Voldemort was visible only as a dark, rippling, faceless figure, shimmering
> and indistinct upon the plinth, clearly struggling to throw off the suffocating mass.
> Then he was gone and the water fell with a crash back into its pool, slopping wildly over the
> sides, drenching the polished floor.

From this it definitely sounds like Voldemort disapparates when he is encased within the water.

> And then Harry's scar burst open and he knew he was dead: it was pain beyond imagining, pain past endurance. 
> He was gone from the hall, he was locked in the coils of a creature with red eyes, so tightly
> bound that Harry did not know where his body ended and the creature’s began: they were fused
> together, bound by pain, and there was no escape 
> And when the creature spoke, it used Harry’s mouth, so that in his agony he felt his jaw move

Nothing in the book seems to suggest Voldemort reappearing, but what it does suggest is him entering Harry, at least more so than any previous encounter Harry has had with Voldemort.

Based on the time difference between the two quotes or more aptly between when Voldemort disappears and then Harry feels the pain, it's safe to say that Voldemort went somewhere before possessing Harry. What is uncertain is whether or not he entered Harry after this fact.

**My opinion**

Whilst the Pensieve and Diary arguments are very convincing and definitely seem to side more with someone entering a memory, I think that Legilimency is the closest representation of the Magic that is the connection between Harry and Voldemort. The quote we have for Legilimency definitely makes no mention of physically entering the memory or even of a feeling of leaving his feet or landing after the fact. I think that both Bellatrix and the opportunity to kill Dumbledore and Harry would make more than a compelling argument for Voldemort to return from wherever he went. Also the time difference between his disappearance and Harry's possession seals it for me, If he was being absorbed into Harry why not do it straight out of the water tomb.

TL:DR **I think he Disapparated but you may think differently**