# Are there other bodily possessions in the Harry Potter stories similar to Voldemort and Quirrell?

Tags: harry-potter, voldemort

So we all know Voldemort's soul (or what remained of it) possessed the body of Quirinus Quirrell.

Quotes from Pottermore:

> Though Hagrid was correct in saying that Quirrell had a ‘brilliant mind,’ the Hogwarts teacher was both naive and arrogant in thinking that he would be able to control an encounter with Voldemort, even in the Dark wizard's weakened state. When Voldemort realised that the young man had a position at Hogwarts, **he took immediate possession of Quirrell, who was incapable of resisting**.
>
> While Quirrell did not lose his soul, he became completely subjugated by Voldemort, who caused a frightful mutation of Quirrell's body: now Voldemort looked out of the back of Quirrell's head and directed his movements, even forcing him to attempt murder. Quirrell tried to put up feeble resistance on occasion, but Voldemort was far too strong for him.

Is there any other example of somebody possessing the body of another in the Harry Potter stories?

Comment: The only one capable of performing such a "possession" would be Voldemort to begin with because he is the only known user of Horcruxes. It is the use of the Horcrux that allows Voldemort to survive as "less than a ghost".

Comment: Wait, what? Is this really from Pottermore? The books never suggest that Quirrel is being controlled by Voldemort, especially before Voldemort actually moves into his head (which only happens after the Gringotts break-in). Seems like a nonsensical retcon at best :S

Comment: Quite literally there is the example of Nagini and Bathilda Bagshot

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, Ginny Weasley in Chamber of Secrets:

> ‘If I say it myself, Harry, I’ve always been able to charm the people I needed. So Ginny poured out her soul to me, and her soul happened to be exactly what I wanted. I grew stronger and stronger on a diet of her deepest fears, her darkest secrets. I grew powerful, far more powerful than little Miss Weasley. Powerful enough to start feeding Miss Weasley a few of my secrets, to start **pouring a little of my soul back into her** ...’ - Tom Riddle
>
> Chamber of Secrets - page 228 - Bloomsbury - chapter 17, The Heir of Slytherin
>
> "I didn't want anyone to talk to me," said Harry, who was feeling more and more nettled.
>   "Well, that was a bit stupid of you," said Ginny angrily, "seeing as you don't know **anyone but me who's been possessed by You-Know-Who**, and I can tell you how it feels." 
>   Harry remained quite still as the impact of these words hit him. Then he wheeled around.
>   "I forgot," he said.
>   "Lucky you," said Ginny coolly.
>
> -Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix

Voldemort also possessed [Harry](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/106191/what-happens-to-voldemorts-physical-body-when-he-possesses-harry) briefly during the Battle at the Ministry

> That power also saved you from **possession by Voldemort**, because he could not bear to reside in a body so full of the force he detests. - Dumbledore to Harry after the battle.
>
> -Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix

Comment: But Voldemort's face didn't appear on the back of Ginny's head. And I considered his interaction with her as more of a "controlling her" instead of "possessing her".